# Pulling dynamic data from server and displaying into PDF using TCPDF

Tags: php, css, pdf, tcpdf

I have been attempting to use PHP to create a dynamic PDF file which can be downloaded. I have included the code below. Document is displaying blank data and nothing on the PDF file.

```
<?php
$output = '';
$quote = $_GET['quote'];
function fetchData(){
    include 'config.php';
    $quote = $_GET['quote'];
    $output = '';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM quote_list, quotation WHERE quote_list.quote_id = quotation.id AND quote_list.quote_id = '$quote'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

    if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $companyName = $row['name'];
    $email = $row['email'];

    $countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(quotation.id) AS countRow FROM quotation WHERE company_name = '$companyName'";
    $countRes = mysqli_query($connect, $countQuery);

    while($countRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($countRes)){
        $count = $countRow['countRow'];
    }

    $quoteNum = $companyName . ' - ' .$count;

    $sqlDate = $row['date'];
    $date = strtotime($sqlDate);
    $date = date('j F Y', $date);

    $output .= "
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col'>
            <img class='logo' src='img/logo.jpg'>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='row margin'>
        <div class='col'>
            <strong><h3>To:" .  $companyName . "</h3>
            Email:". $email."</strong>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='row margin'>
        <div class='col'>Quotation Number:".  $quoteNum ."</div>
    </div>

    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col'>Issue Date:". $date ."</div>
    </div>

    <div class='row margin'>
        <div class='col'>
            <p>Further to your enquiry, please find attached our quotation based on your discussed requirements. If you have any other queries, amendments or your requirements change please do not hesitate to contact me.</p>
            <p>Thank you for the opportunity to quote on this project.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='row margin'>
        <div class='col'>
            <h1>Your quotation:</h1>
            <table class='table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-responsive'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Quote Details
                        </th>
                        <th class='float-right'>
                            Amount Quoted
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>";

                $query = "SELECT * FROM quote_list, quotation WHERE quote_list.quote_id = quotation.id AND quote_list.quote_id = '$quote'";
                $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
                $total = 0;
                $discount = 0;

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    $title = $row['title'];
                    $price = $row['price'];
                    $discount = $row['discount'];
                    $total += $price;

                    $ouput .=
                    "
                    <tr>
                        <td>".
                            $title."
                        </td>
                        <td class='float-right'>
                            £".$price.
                            "
                        </td>
                    </tr>    
                    ";
                }

                $final = $total-$discount;



                $output .= "
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class='float-right'><em><strong>Total: </strong></em>£".$total."</br><em><strong>Discount: </strong></em>£".$discount."</br><em><strong>Quotation Price: </strong></em>£".$final."</td>
                    </tr>
               </tbody>
                </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='row margin'>
        <div class='col'>
            <h1>Terms and Conditions</h1>
            <h2>Our Quotation</h2>
            <p>The above costs are inclusive of VAT, which will be charged where applicable. NI Flyers Print & Design quotations are valid for 30 days. Design costs are based on our understanding of your initial brief. Any additional amends/change to brief will be advised prior to invoicing. The right of design creations remains exclusively with NI Flyers Print & Design including economic and moral rights. Acceptance of this quotation includes a non-exclusive licence for the use of the works outlined above. An exclusive licence may be obtained at an additional cost.</p>

            <h2>Additional photographic or illustration-based imagery</h2>
            <p>Sourced photography or illustration this will be an additional cost to the design process. Imagery can be sourced either from stock library at £30.00 per image, or commissioned at cost, which will always be pre-quoted. If attendance to manage or art direct photoshoots is required this will be based on our standard hourly rate of £50 per hour. Additional photoshoot props or services will be charged accordingly.</p>

        </div>
    </div>   
";
   }
        return $output;
   }

if(isset($_GET['viewPDF'])){
  require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');  
  $obj_pdf = new TCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);  
  $obj_pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);  
  $obj_pdf->SetTitle("Generate HTML Table Data To PDF From MySQL Database Using TCPDF In PHP");  
  $obj_pdf->SetHeaderData('', '', PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);  
  $obj_pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));  
  $obj_pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));  
  $obj_pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');  
  $obj_pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);  
  $obj_pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, '10', PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);  
  $obj_pdf->setPrintHeader(false);  
  $obj_pdf->setPrintFooter(false);  
  $obj_pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 10);  
  $obj_pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 11);  
  $obj_pdf->AddPage();
  $output .= fetchData();
  $obj_pdf->writeHTML($output);  
  $obj_pdf->Output('Quote_' . $quote . '.pdf', 'I');
}  
 ?>
```

Is there something I have done wrong in making this document? I was following a tutorial and documentation on this and cannot seem to make it load at all. Always a blank PDF document for some reason. Are there any simpler tools to be used when coming to PDF creation via PHP dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that your fetchData() function is not returning anything.

If I amend:

```
$obj_pdf->writeHTML($output);
```

To read ..

```
$obj_pdf->writeHTML('hello world');
```

Then this correctly shows in the PDF. This would seem to confirm that your TCPDF code is correct.

When I run your code locally then I don't get anything returned by your fetchData() function. Obviously I don't have your database set-up but I think this is where your issue is.

Have a go adding some echos throughout the function and make sure that what you think is being returned is being returned.

Comment: I have attempted to echo data out, still no return. Something is up with my fetchData() function not doing something. Thanks. The page I am expecting is this -> http://adonnelly759.students.cs.qub.ac.uk/niflyers/viewQuote.php?quoteID=19, just in PDF format

Comment: Yep, HTML looks good. This is a definitely a query issue. Doesn't look like $connect is defined in $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query); so that's probably something to look at